# How to dynamically assign ID for each object with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to dynamically assign ID for each object I add in an array. I have tried assigning the initial id as 0 then incrementing that id when a new object is added in the array but it didn't help. Here is the code I am working with. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

```
const checkStorage = () => {
    const input = document.querySelector('#taskInput');
    // Update localstorage if there is value in input
    if(input.value) {
        // Task object
        const task = {
            name: input.value,
            id: 0
        }
        
        // If there is nothing in localstorage create an empty array and push the task object in the array then set the array to localstorage
        if(localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null) {
            const tasks = [];
            tasks.push(task);
            localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks)); // We now have the first object with the id of 0
        // If there is a task array already in localstorage then add new task object to it and set it back to localstorage
        } else {
            const tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
            // I tried looping through the tasks array and incrementing the id for any item added next but it didn't help
            tasks.push(task);
            localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: `tasks.push({name: input.value, id: tasks.length})` when existing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the length of the array to set a new ID (`tasks.length`).

```js
const checkStorage = () => {
  // Create new task
  const task = {
    name: input.value,
    id: 0
  };
  
  // Get tasks from localStorage
  const localTasks = localStorage.getItem("tasks");
  
  // If there are no tasks in localStorage
  if(!localTasks) {
    const tasks = [task];
    // Save to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
  }else{
    // Get tasks from localStorage
    const tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
    
    // Update the ID
    tasks.push({
      ...task,
      id: tasks.length
    });
    
    // Save to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
  }
  
  // Just so we can log the output
  const latest = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
  console.log(latest);
}

// Input and button controls
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const btn = document.querySelector("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", checkStorage);

// Since localStorage doesn't work in sandbox i created my own
class fakeLocalStorage {
  data = new Map();
  getItem = key => this.data.get(key) || null;
  setItem = (key, data) => this.data.set(key, data);
};
const localStorage = new fakeLocalStorage();
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<button>Add Task</button>
```